# If combining vectors of same length in R, should you have the final dimensions as the sum of both vector lengths?

Tags: r

```
 train.finaldtm1 <-dtmFinal[(1:100),(1:100)]
 train.finaldtm2 <-dtmFinal[(201:300),(201:300)]
 train.dtmcombine <- append(train.finaldtm1,train.finaldtm2)
```

I tried appending two different vectors in R of equal lengths. Shouldn't I have a final dimensions of 200 by 200 as it is the sum of both vectors? I'm getting a different number of columns.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMIk3.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use `dplyr::bind_rows`

```
final <- dplyr::bind_rows(train.finaldtm1, train.finaldtm2)
```

Since `train.finaldtm1` and `train.finaldtm2` have different columns first 100 rows would have `NA` values for column 101 to 200 and next 100 rows would have `NA`s for column 1 to 100.

Comment: Hi Ronak, What if my data set is a document term matrix? Would I still be able to use that or dplyr only applies to data frames.

Comment: I don't know if it will work with document term matrix. You can try and let me know. If it doesn't work can you provide a reproducible example so that it would be easier to help?